# Directory name as a variable

Tags: macros, file-lookup, environment-variables

Is it possible to use the directory where the current tex-file is in as variable?

For example, suppose I am in the directory

```
/path/to/foo/
```

and compile there the document
`bar.tex` (absolute path is `/path/to/foo/bar.tex`).

Is it possible to use `/path/to/foo` or even `foo` as a variable in TeX/LaTeX like it is possible to use `bar` with variable `\jobname`? Is there an (array-like) TeX internal macro that is populated with the segments of a path to the input file being compiled?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeX has no notion of the current directory tree, since it's written to work also with operating systems where this has no sense. If you are on a Unix system, you can run `pdflatex` from the command line with

```
pdflatex "\def\mypath{$(pwd)}\input{file}"
```

where `file.tex` is your main document, thus exploiting shell command substitution. The `$(pwd)` syntax is for `bash`, other shells may require `` `pwd` ``, instead.

Comment: Probably the best solution. Though this of course doesn't work if you use `\input{somedir/file}`. (Btw, if you are using LuaTeX, then the current dir (which might or might not coincide with the directory of the TeX file) is available as `os.env.PWD`.)

Answer (score 17):

There is the [`currfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile) package which gives you the file name and relative path of the current input file.
Since v0.6 from 2012/05/06 it is also possible to get absolute paths if the document is compiled with the `-recorder` argument. Note that this argument is already used by `latexmk`, so if you are using it there is no extra effort.

The simplest way is to load `currfile` with the `abspath` option:

```
% Compile with: (pdf|xe|lua|)latex -recorder filename
% Needs two runs with MiKTeX, one with TeX Live
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}[2012/05/06]

\begin{document}

% These macros will show the data of the current
% input file, i.e. inside an \input file they will
% show different values
Absolute directory: \currfileabsdir

Absolute path: \currfileabspath

\end{document}
```

See the manual for all other provided macros (file base name, extension, etc.) if you also have need for them.

If you don't need the full functionality of `currfile` (which will update several macros for every input file), then you can use the sub-package `currfile-abspath` directly:

```
% Compile with: (pdf|xe|lua|)latex -recorder filename
% Needs two runs with MiKTeX, one with TeX Live
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currfile-abspath}

\getmainfile % get real main file (can be different than jobname in some cases)
\getabspath{\themainfile} % or use \jobname.tex instead (not as safe)
\let\mainabsdir\theabsdir % save result away (macro will be overwritten by the next \getabspath
\let\mainabspath\theabspath % save result away (macro will be overwritten by the next \getabspath

\begin{document}

Absolute directory: \mainabsdir

Absolute path: \mainabspath

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @MartinScharrer , unfortunately this doesn't work on my computer. Maybe because I'm using Windows 10?

Comment: @K.Mulier: Are you sure you use the `-recorder` argument of the LaTeX executable?

Comment: how do I "use the '-recorder' argument on the LaTeX executable"? I use the TeXstudio IDE to develop my LaTeX documents. The compilation is a simple click on a button. I'm not really familiar with the things happening during compilation behind the scenes of my IDE. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @K.Mulier: Sorry, don't know TeXstudio. Look after "Settings", "Compiler", or similar, in the menu.