# Citation not found if bib file in parent directory

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

My citations work fine when the `sources.bib` file is within the same directory as my `.tex` file, as shown here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\nocite{textbook}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sources}

\end{document}
```

Here is the `sources.bib` file:

```
@book{textbook,
    author = {First, Last},
    title = {title},
}
```

My bibliography shows up just fine. However, if I simply move `sources.bib` outside into the parent directory, and adjust the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\nocite{textbook}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{../sources}

\end{document}
```

I receive the errors:

```
Citation `textbook' undefined
Empty `thebibliography' environment
There were undefined references.
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: You need to put your `.bib` file either in the current directory or in a place that TeX/BibTeX will search by default (or 'force' the issue, which I don't recommend).  If you have TeX Live installed, you may (not sure about Windows) be able simply to type `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` to find the base of your local tree.  For me that gives: `~/texmf`, so I can construct the BibTeX branch of that tree: `mkdir ~/texmf/bibtex/bib` and put my bibliography file there (or create a link to it from that directory).  For MikTeX, I believe the arrangement is more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Although it should have no effect in this case, it's better to keep the Minimum Working Example (MWE) the smallest possible, and provide all the files required to test it. The MWE is lacking the `fancy` style definition. Removing it and `\everymath`, and adding the content of the bibfile, this MWE works for me:

./main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\cite{knuth1986texbook}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{../sources}

\end{document}
```

../sources.bib

```
@book{knuth1986texbook,
  keywords = {book},
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bibby, D.},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
```

Just to be sure, remove all the auxiliary files and compile the whole sequence again (pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex). Is it still not working?

Comment: sure, sorry about that. Even with this it does not work.

To note, I am using latexing in sublime text, which "autobuilds" for me. I'd presume that such a minimal example should work regardless. I tried in Texshop and it fails as well. It seems to find the file (no "file not found" errors), but the actual reference cannot be found.

Comment: Could you run it from the command line? Just to be sure it's not due to 'sublime', the plugin or Texshop failing.

Comment: On my computer (Windows 8.1), it is important to clean all the auxiliary files generated before compiling the tex file again, or I got the error message that the *.bib file can not be found.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the code posted in [U.Martinez-Corral's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203372/115852), unfortunately it's not work for me (Windows10 + sublime Text 3 (Build 3126) + LaTeXTools + Texlive).

This is a limitation of BibTeX:

> Relative paths requiring upward directory traversal (..) don't work when using BibTeX and an output directory. This is a limitation of BibTeX, which doesn't really support the concept of an output directory.
>   [Citation not found if bib file in parent directory](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1180#issuecomment-317664527)

## Solution 1

Use absolute path instead.

```
\bibliography{../sources}                         % relative path: don't work
\bibliography{E:/GitKraken/test/sources}          % absolute path: work
```

## Solution 2

My solution is using `currfile-abspath` package to build an absolute path `\bibliography{\mainabsdir/../sources}`.

./main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{currfile-abspath}

\getmainfile % get real main file (can be different than jobname in some cases)
\getabspath{\themainfile} % or use \jobname.tex instead (not as safe)
\let\mainabsdir\theabsdir % save result away (macro will be overwritten by the next \getabspath
\let\mainabspath\theabspath % save result away (macro will be overwritten by the next \getabspath

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth1986texbook}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\mainabsdir/../sources}

\end{document}
```

See Also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54891/115852